# I have a problem creating a spectrogram from audio files in WAV format in an excel file

Tags: python, excel, audio

I have a dataset as an excel file In the file, I have columns.
One of the columns contains the audio files in wav format and the rest of the columns are a description of the audio file
For example:-

The first column, the first row (audio file in wav format)
The second column, the first row (Is the reading true or false)
The third column, the first row (the type of error)
The fourth column, first row (error location)
The fifth column, first row (explanation of the error)

I need to enter the excel file so that I can read the first audio file and convert it to a spectrogram and store the image in a seventh column in front of the audio

And so on for each audio, to convert each audio to spectrograms and store it in the same excel file in front of its own sound

I have reached the conversion of sound to septogram, but only the first sound is converted to septogram, and the rest of the sounds are not converted.

Secondly, how can I store a septogram image in the same excel file so that each audio has its own septogram image in the same row but in a different column?

```
def get_wav_info(wav_file):
for index_num,row in tqdm(metadata.iterrows()):
    file_name = str(row["Verse location"])
    data, rate = sf.read(file_name)
    return data, rate

def graph_spectrogram(wav_file):
    data, rate = get_wav_info(file_name)
    nfft = 200 # Length of each window segment
    fs = 8000 # Sampling frequencies
    noverlap = 120 # Overlap between windows
    nchannels = data.ndim
    if nchannels == 1:
        pxx, freqs, bins, im = plt.specgram(data, nfft, fs, noverlap = noverlap)
    elif nchannels == 2:
        pxx, freqs, bins, im = plt.specgram(data[:,0], nfft, fs, noverlap = noverlap)
    return pxx

for index_num,row in tqdm(metadata.iterrows()):
        plt.figure(figsize=(14, 5))
        x = graph_spectrogram(str(index_num))
```

Comment: Your `graph_spectrogram` function doesn't use its argument for anything. Is `file_name` a global?

Comment: Yes is a global

Comment: So what is the purpose of the argument `wav_file`, which you ignore? Actually, `get_wav_info` also ignores its argument by the same name. And it assigns to a *local* variable `file_name` (not that it matters, since you ignore its value anyway). And it returns the information in the first row, so the loop doesn't seem very necessary.

Comment: I think you started to write code before you were done thinking about how the information should flow. A good start would be to remove all global variables - that forces you to think. (It's never too soon to stop using global variables.)